# Azure cloud service: Modify the service definition

Tags: azure

I have a virtual machine inside cloud service
i need to install ssl certificate on this cloud service
i saw this post about it
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal/

but how can i make step 2? 
i tried the rest of the steps and made them
but i have no idea about step 2, i don't have a web role
i have vm

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer by @Bruno Faria on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/questions/722796/install-ssl-certificate-on-azure-cloud-service-vm/722811#722811) as I am not allowed to mark this question is duplicate of the one asked there:

---

> The tutorial you are following is for web/worker roles cloud services
>   and not Virtual Machines. Although a VM uses the cloud service layer,
>   it's not the same thing. All you have to do is to install the
>   certificate as you would in any windows server machine and add the
>   Host A register to your DNS provider.
>
> [SSL Certificates CSR Creation :: IIS 8 and IIS 8.5](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-8.htm)
>
> [IIS 8 and IIS 8.5 SSL Certificate Installation](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8.htm)
>
> **Update**: In case of Apache (Linux)
>
> [OpenSSL CSR Creation for Apache SSL](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-apache.htm)
>
> [Apache SSL Certificate Installation](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm)
>
> Also, make sure to reserve your public in order to keep it in a event
>   of shutdown or restart of your virtual machines.
>
> [Reserved IP Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/)

---